# localhost:8000 working but mywebsite:8000 with etc/hosts modified doesn't work

Tags: django

Everything is in the title: I'm launching my webserver (Django / Python) on port 8000.

```
/home/olivier/my_venv3.8/bin/python3 /home/olivier/pycharm-2018.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 40761 --file /home/olivier/projects/evalr/manage.py runserver 8000
pydev debugger: process 5923 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 193.5662.61)
http://evalr.hqf.fr:8000/fr/assistant/
http://evalr.hqf.fr:8000/fr/sessions/
pydev debugger: process 5935 is connecting

http://evalr.hqf.fr:8000/fr/assistant/
http://evalr.hqf.fr:8000/fr/sessions/
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

I've added in my `/etc/hosts` this line : `127.0.1.1   evalr.hqf.fr`   and when I ping it, it correctly shows "`127.0.0.1`"

When I try go on `http://evalr.hqf.fr:8000` I get connection refused and when I try to go on `http:/localhost:8000` it works.

The problem is that when I try to go on `http://evalr.hqf.fr:8000` I dont have any trace on the server side, i.e. it stays here:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 03, 2020 - 20:41:31
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'evalr.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

And when I go on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I get a log of every single access like:

```
[03/Jan/2020 20:47:42] "GET /fr/sessions/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[03/Jan/2020 20:47:42] "GET /fr/login/?next=/fr/sessions/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7031
[03/Jan/2020 20:47:43] "GET /static/vendors/css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 54456
 ................ blabla............;
[03/Jan/2020 20:47:43] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

I've even tried to reboot (even though I'm on Linux, which talks by itself - no reboot needed), so I'm stuck because everything should work fine. What am I missing?

Comment: did you add your domain to ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Comment: Hey Oliver. What is the reason to set 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in /etc/hosts it should be 127.0.0.1 instead

Also check the ALLOWED_HOSTS and you could try running it with: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get a connection refused when using the hostname, and do not see any logging from your application, makes me think that you are dealing with DNS caching. My favorite way to test this is using `curl`, since it can show you both the IP address and response of an HTTP request. Try the following command:

```
curl -Iv -X GET http://evalr.hqf.fr:8000
```

Did it resolve to 127.0.0.1? If so, did you get a response? If so, did you see logs in your application?

If the answer to these question is yes, then try to clear the DNS and browser cache.